# Why am I getting a segmentation error? What is the reason getting output as numbers instead of strings?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I am aware of why segmentation faults occur, but I am not able to find out the error with the following code I made to split a string on the basis of whitespaces.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;
vector<string> split(const string& s)
{
    //cout << "HERE";
    vector<string> tab;
    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < s.size(); a++)
    {
        string temp = to_string(s[a]);
        while(to_string(s[a]) != " ")
        {
            a++;
            temp = temp + s[a];
        }
        tab.push_back(temp);
    }
    return tab;
}   


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    while(n--)
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        vector<string> temp = split(s);
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << temp[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if I comment out the while loop in the split function, I get numbers when I print out the resulting strings. Is it because of to_string? If I use `typeid(variable).name()` on the resulting strings that I get when I am printing them in the main function, I get this: `NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`.

Comment: What is the program supposed to do? Also, since you seem to be on Linux, have you tried using gdb?

Comment: `std::string::find` and `std::string::substr` is enough for you

Comment: Are all these tags really necessary?

Comment: And back to your question, `std::to_string` doesn't have overload for `char`

Answer (score 3):

To answer your final question:

C++ often, but not always, treats a `char` value as numeric, and certainly does if you pass it to `to_string`. So `to_string(' ')` will return `"32"` (generally), which is the character code for a space converted to a string in decimal.

To convert a character to the corresponding single-element string use e.g.  `string(1, ' ')`.

For your segmentation fault the debugger is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your split function is buggy. Your program will always crush because `while(to_string(s[a]) != " ")` condition on the while loop will cause infinite loop.

It seems strange to me you are using to_string(s[a]). Lets say s[a] is really space char even in this case toString(" ") will return a std::string which contains "32". And "32" is not equal " " so this will cause your loop run infinitely.

And since in the loop you are increasing the index like below.

```
    a++;  ---> You increase the index in infite loop so a can go to millions 
    temp = temp + s[a]; ---> you are using the index and causing index out of range.
```

You will cause index out of range error.